# Google tag manager adds tag at wrong place in Angular url

Tags: angularjs, google-tag-manager

On a regular html page (*not* Angular), I have a link to a page that uses Angular. Eg:

https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeRecipients&operations=delete

However, the GTM (Google Tag Manager) is re-writing the URL to:

https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/&_ga=1.892xxx#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeRecipients&operations=delete

This breaks the Angular router on the destination page.

I had expected / wanted the `&_ga=1.892xxx` to be appended to the very end of the url.

Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Answer courtesy of [Simo Ahava via the GTM Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/lUcDZjqwVBg;context-place=forum/tag-manager):

> It's not GTM per se, it's actually analytics.js (the Universal Analytics library) that does this. The reason for the bug is that the URL scheme on your site is unconventional, since query parameters should come before the hash fragment. GA does a pattern match for the query symbol ?, finds it, and then adds its own query parameters to the correct place - just before the fragment.
>
> To fix this, you need to tell GA to recognize the hash as a delimiter, so in the "Cross-domain settings" of your GA Tags, select "True" from the "Use Hash as delimiter" menu.